# What is the difference between lynx and pandoc?

Tags: output, download, lynx, pandoc

[In this thread](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/694324/how-to-download-an-html-file-as-plain-text) I was suggested to do an action with `lynx` or `pandoc`.

To my understanding, both programs can output an *all backend* and *solely or primarily textual* webpage, in console, pretty much as this webpage would be rendered on a web browser.

I googled "lynx pandoc diff" (without quote marks) but didn't find a succinct explanation about the difference between the two programs.

What is the difference between `lynx` and `pandoc`?

### Update

I should have read a bit, an intro at least, about these utilities in `man` before publishing this question but due to not doing so and losing time in comments together with another user I do it symbolically to punish myself, better late than never as the principle goes.

I have found after executing `man pandoc`:

**pandoc - general markup converter**

> Pandoc  is  a  Haskell  library for converting from one markup format to another, and a command-line tool that
> uses this library.  It can read Markdown, CommonMark, PHP Markdown Extra, GitHub-Flavored Markdown, MultiMark‐
> down, and (subsets of) Textile, reStructuredText, HTML, LaTeX, MediaWiki markup, TWiki markup, Haddock markup,
> OPML, Emacs Org mode, DocBook, txt2tags, EPUB, ODT and Word docx; and it can write plain text.

I have found after executing `man lynx`:

**lynx - a general purpose distributed information browser for the World Wide Web**

> Lynx  is  a  fully-featured  World  Wide  Web  (WWW)  client  for users running cursor-addressable, character-cell display devices (e.g., vt100 terminals, vt100
> emulators running on Windows 95/NT/XP/7/8 or any POSIX platform, or any other “curses-oriented” display).  It will  display  hypertext  markup  language  (HTML)
> documents containing links to files residing on the local system, as well as files residing on remote systems running Gopher, HTTP, FTP, WAIS, and NNTP servers.
> Current versions of Lynx run on Unix, VMS, Windows 95/NT/XP/7/8, DOS DJGPP and OS/2.

> Lynx can be used to access information on the World Wide Web, or to build information systems intended primarily for local access.  For example, Lynx  has  been
> used to build several Campus Wide Information Systems (CWIS).  In addition, Lynx can be used to build systems isolated within a single LAN.

I am anyway happy with publishing this question because if someone not familiar with the `man` culture or websites describing the utilities and stuck and feel overwhelmed, this post might help this person.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/134787/discussion-on-question-by-lahor-what-is-the-essential-difference-between-lynx-an).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Lynx is a browser. Interactive application which you can use to browse the web, minus graphics.

Pandoc is a converter. It takes a file in one format and converts into another.

Comment: Wouldn't you say that pandoc is also a browser in the sense that it can accesses and somewhat "render" webpages? Thanks,

Comment: While both can download html using http(s) and convert it to plain text, the similarities more or less end there. You can't use pandoc interactively, as @white-owl points out. Pandoc can, however, convert lots of other file formats, and output lots of other file formats, which lynx wasn't designed to do.

Comment: @Lahor lynx is a web browser, that does all the things web browsers do: accesses remote pages, displays them, and lets you fill out forms, etc. pandoc is a file format converter and does none of the things that a browser does. they are completely unrelated aside from the fact that both have the ability to parse html and render it to plain text

Comment: @Fox I think what you wrote should be an answer, especially `they are completely unrelated aside from the fact that both have the ability to parse html and render it to plain text`.